# Matlab regression analysis. Fitlm vs Regress

Tags: matlab, regression

Not too much of a coding question but a conceptual question.

What is the difference between using Matlabs' fitlm and regress functions? I expected them to be the same but when I run them I get different outputs.

Specifically

```
mdl = fitlm(predictors,response)
```

vs

```
[b,bint,r,rint,stats] = regress(response,predictors)
```

Where I use 'stats' to get the r2 etc.

Documentation:

[Fitlm](https://au.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitlm.html)

[Regress](https://au.mathworks.com/help/stats/regress.html)

Comment: [the same question along with the answer can be found there](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/560648-what-are-the-differences-between-regress-and-fitlm#:~:text=Unlike%20regress%2C%20the%20fitlm%20function,'%20name%2Dvalue%20pair%20argument.)

Comment: Ok, but this doesn't explain why I get different results, which is what I was hoping to explain.

Comment: Then edit your question with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), along with a more specific question.